# Find the fixed point for map and determine the stability

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find the fixed points for the map  $x_{n+1}=x_n^2$
 and determinee their stability.

I did

$x_1=x_0^2$

$x_2=x_1^2=x_0^4$

and sketch a graph but couldnt continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fixed point is a point $x$ such that $x^2=x$, ie either zero or 1. Now, zero is stable, because if $|x_1|<1$ then $x_n \rightarrow 0$, but one isn't stable, because if $x_1$ is greater than 1 then repeated squaring will take $x_n$ to infinity, and if $x_1$ is a bit smaller than 1 then $x_n$ converges to zero.